# Set required for Tax/VAT field for a specific store in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, checkout

I have a magento store with different store view. I want to show Tax/Vat field on checkout but it will mandatory for Italy only.

**What i have done:**
After selection store view, from customer->customer configuration i have set Show VAT number on Storefront **YES**
and Show VAT Number set Required.

In checkout page VAT field is showing but required validation not working.

I have tried overwrite with jQuery but didnt succeed. I guess adding attribute in knockjs might be a option but i am really dont know. Can any one help me out. I am stuck.

magento version 2.2.5

Answer (score 0):

I got an alternative solution.
update **checkout_index_index.xml**

Check closely this line for vat_id `<item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>`

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="vat_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

It works for me. 
NB: But i am sure most of the cases set **VAT ID required** at checkout it should be done configuring from admin.